# Translate php soap request to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, soap

I need to send a soap request to a web service using javascript, i was given this php example code, but i do not want to learn the language yet just just for one piece of code.

```
$uuid = "xxxx";
$param = array("uuid"=>new SoapVar($uuid,
                                   XSD_STRING,
                                   "string",   
                                   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
);


$key1 = implode("", $wsdatek);
$keys = array('key' => new SoapVar(sha1($key1),
XSD_STRING,
"string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
);
$datosws = array("local_cert" => "../cert/www.page.com.pem",
"trace" => true, "exceptions" => true
);
```

This question is derived from the unsuccessful research made on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356234/arrays-in-jquery-soap) one

Comment: Sending a soap request via javascript is relatively unsafe if you are inputting login details or such, is it just because you don't want to learn PHP you are doing it?

Comment: It is because i am developing a cross platform app built entirely on HTML and JS, where no php is being used at all. Yes, it might be unsafe but it is the mechanism imposed by the payment service.

Comment: A payment service that tells you not to use a server-side language to handle login details?

Comment: sounds even worst when you write it like that. All the messages are encrypted with a certificate given by the company which i have to put on my mobile app and make the calls directly to their web services

Comment: if you need me to evaluate any more just link me to your php SoapVar function and let me know whats in $wsdatek.

Comment: @RobertPounder You left me worried about the safeness of the encrypted soap request, which i considered to be safe for transmission purposes. Given that it would be a mobile app not subject to traditional browser attacks, should i consider the method to be inherently unsafe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70389/discussion-between-nicolasz-and-robert-pounder).

Comment: even in a mobile browser it is inherently unsafe, there are mobile browsers with view-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did one example think this is what you want? Assume you can work out the rest on your own.

```
var datosws = [["local_cert","../cert/www.page.com.pem"],["trace",true],["exceptions",true]];
```

They keys var incase you get confused

```
var XSD_STRING = ""; //const
var key1 = ""; // sha1 the key
var keys = [["key",key1],XSD_STRING,"string","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using jQuery on top of you javascript, you should try this plugin:
https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap